# How show wildmenu automagically, without the need to press <Tab>?

Tags: vim

In my Vimrc, I have this set:

```
set wildmenu       
set wildmode=full
set wildignorecase
```

When you are typing like NERDTree, and press Tab you see the suggests results in your statusline. Looks awesome, right?

I would like to have a function, that every time you press a character in the command, the Tab is automatically pressed. So every time, you type a character, you see the suggested commands in the statusline. Like Emacs M-x.

I looked in help in the autocommands, but none of the events described the event (pressing characters in command line).

Anyone have a idea which event I mean?

Comment: set wildmode=list:longest,full is my preferred setting for wildmode. It shows a list if there are multiple matches and makes it easier to spot what you need. That I believe is the closest, I can think of, to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want [wilder.nvim](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim).

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event. You're probably thinking of `InsertCharPre`, but that's limited to insert mode. You would need to override every printable character in command-line mode via `:cmap`, but that could have other side effects, or interfere with some plugins.

Better think hard whether you really need this. The wild menu is modeled after shell completion, and that has to be explicitly triggered via `<Tab>`, too.